# Pourquoi y a-t-il un « ne » et un « se » avant « apprendre » dans « La pratique ne s'apprend que par l'aide de professionnels expérimentés » ?

Tags: grammaire, négation, verbes-pronominaux, passif

J'ai lu cette phrase dans un forum, en lisant des choses sur la différence entre « à », « par» et « avec l'aide de ». Et l'un des exemples, c'était:

> La pratique ne s'apprend que par l'aide de professionnels expérimentés … financés par l'aide de donateurs.

Ce qui me confond, c'est qu'il y a un « se » avant « apprendre ». Je n'ai pas pu trouver une définition sur internet. Et pourquoi y a-t-il un « ne » ? Est-ce un *ne explétif* ? Ou quelque chose d'autre ?

(Si vous pouvez répondre, pouvez-vous ajouter le traduction de la phrase en anglais? Merci!)

Answer (score 3):

The « **ne...que** » form is used the same way in English we say "only."

> For example: « Je **ne** fais **que** regarder » = "I'm only watching"

When employing pronominal verbs, the reflexive pronoun (i.e. *me, te, se, nous, vous, se*) goes after the *ne* (e.g. « Je ne **me** lave que le matin »)

That sentence could be translated as,

> "Experience is **only** gained with help from seasoned professionals...financed with help from donors."

Comment: Note that a French paraphrase could be : "La pratique s'apprend uniquement à l'aide de professionnels expérimentés ..."

Answer (score 3):

Dans ta phrase, s'apprendre (**se** apprendre) est un **verbe pronominal**.

Comme *se laver, s'abstenir, se contenter*.

Plus précisément, c'est un  **verbe pronominal réfléchi**, qui signifie que l'action est exercée par le sujet sur lui-même.

> "La pratique ne **s**'apprend" — on apprend la pratique à soi-même !

C'est plus simple à comprendre avec le verbe **se laver** par exemple

> Je **me** lave — veut dire qu'on lave son corps, qu'on lave soi-même

Les verbes pronominaux peuvent être utilisées dans d'autres circonstances, pour exprimer la réciprocité par exemple

> Marc et moi, nous allons **nous** rencontrer : Je vais rencontrer Marc et Marc, lui aussi, va me rencontrer

Comment: Donc, signifie-t-il "The practice only learns by the help of experiences professionals"?

Comment: *experienced :)

Comment: @BlobGod when used reflexively, to me a better translation is usually "taught" or in this case "learned" with the help of professionals

Comment: So it could be "to be taught"?